# Assigning value to varaible with a cascading drop down menu

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm pretty new to this, and I am kind of running out of ideas to make this work.

Here's the situation; for a calculator-tool, I need to create a cascading drop-down menu where the second option selected corresponds with a value that then should be used as a variable in a formula. My issue currently is that I don't know how to assign a value to each option. I think I can figure out the rest of the code, but I've been stuck on this for a little while.

Here's the cascading drop-down menu I have so far. I changed the options, just to make sure it is in no way relevant to the project I'm working on. Let's, for the sake of clarity, say I need to assign the value of the car to the corresponding option, and use that to calculate the tax, which would be a certain percentage of the vehicle's value, later on.

```
<script>
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
    {
    document.getElementById("Model").length = 0;
    switch (listindex)
    {
    case "Mazda" :
        document.getElementById("model").options[0]=new Option("Select Model","");
        document.getElementById("model").options[1]=new Option("MX-5","MX-5");
        document.getElementById("model").options[2]=new Option("RX-7","RX-7");
        document.getElementById("model").options[3]=new Option("323","323");
        document.getElementById("model").options[4]=new Option("626","626");
        document.getElementById("model").options[5]=new Option("MX-6","MX-6");
        break;
    case "Subaru" :
        document.getElementById("model").options[0]=new Option("Please select model","");
        document.getElementById("model").options[1]=new Option("Impreza","Impreza");
        document.getElementById("model").options[2]=new Option("Forester","Forester");
        break;
    case "Nissan" :
        document.getElementById("model").options[0]=new Option("Please select model","");
        document.getElementById("model").options[1]=new Option("350Z","350Z");
        document.getElementById("model").options[2]=new Option("370Z","370Z");
        document.getElementById("model").options[3]=new Option("Pulsar","Pulsar");
        document.getElementById("model").options[4]=new Option("GT-R","GT-R");
        document.getElementById("model").options[5]=new Option("Skyline","Skyline");
      }
    return true;
    }
    </script>
<div class="category_div" id="category_div">Select manufacturer:
                <select name="category" class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                <option value="">Select manufacturer</option>
                <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
                <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
                <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
<div class="category_div" id="category_div">Select manufacturer:
                <select name="category" class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                <option value="">Select manufacturer</option>
                <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
                <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
                <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
               </select>
            </div>
```

I do apologise if I've made any mistakes in changing the code to make it irrelevant to the project. As I said, I'm pretty new to this, so please be kind :)

Comment: First and foremost, **`#id`s must be unique**: 1. each `<select>` has `id='category'` which is invalid, 2. each `<div>` wrapped around a `<select>` has `id='category_div'` which is invalid. Next is: `document.getElementById('model')...`
There is no element with `id='model'`. This is fundamental JavaScript that should've been rectified before posting a question involving more advanced JavaScript. When you have corrected those mistakes, the question might be worth answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass en event to your function by putting `this` as an argument in the HTML (see the `onchange` in the HTML below). When we call the `test` function in the JavaScript code, the event argument is passed, which contains all the information about your dropdown menu. The `event.value` contains your selection, so you can use this to determine what value you would like to add.

JavaScript:

```
const test = (event) => {
  let toAdd = 0
  if (event.value == "Nissan") toAdd = 10
  if (event.value == "Subaru") toAdd = 5
  console.log(5 + toAdd)
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="category_div" id="category_div">
      Select manufacturer:
    <select name="category" class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="test(this)">
      <option value="">Select manufacturer</option>
      <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
      <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
      <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

If you want to make your code smoother, you can destructure the value property at the start of the function, so you can write `value` in curley braces as an argument, rather than `event`. Then you can reference `value` going forward, instead of `event.value`...

```
const test = ({value}) => {
```

and...

```
if (value == "Nissan") toAdd = 10
```

[Here's a pen with the code above](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1011)